# Capitalise a specific letter of a string in SQL

Tags: sql

How would I capitalise every letter 'a' in for example 'angela'

```
SELECT LOWER(SUBSTRING('angela',1,CHARINDEX('a', 'angela')-1))+UPPER(RIGHT(LEFT('angela',CHARINDEX('a', 'angela')),1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING('angela',CHARINDEX('a', 'angela')+1,LEN('angela')))
```

This works but only on one letter.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Very difficult... if using SQL Server I recommend a CLR function so you can do it in C# which is much easier.

Comment: What RDBMS? `Replace(text,'a','A')`  angela becomes AngelA... abracadabra becomes AbrAcAdAbrA  either replace should work, or the equivalent, if supported, in your RDBMS

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most RDBMS support `replace()`.  In Excel it's called `substitute()`.  Gotta love consistency

```
SELECT Replace('angela','a','A')
Gives us: AngelA

SELECT Replace('the sky was the darkest blue','the','')
Gives us:' sky was  darkest blue'

SELECT Replace('the sky was the darkest blue','the ','')
Gives us:'sky was darkest blue'
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8833fbdf9bdcaf99e477f73c790d55b9)

```
Replace(<StringToEvaluate>, <test to search for>, <text to overwrite with>)
```